# Train and bus tickets between Tallinn and Tartu

Tags: trains, buses, estonia, tallinn

I and my girlfriend are going to Tartu on the last week of June, from June 21 to June 28. We've got the ship from Helsinki to Tallinn and back sorted, but we still need to actually get to Tartu.

We are planning to go to Tartu by train from Tallinn and return by bus. Where, how and when should we buy the tickets?

Answer (score 2):

You can get to Tartu by [Simple/Lux Express](https://luxexpress.eu/et/tallinn-tartu). You can find tickets [from 1€](http://www.simpleexpress.eu/et/hinnad-alates-1-eur) if booked in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use official ticket seller  **Tpilet**.ee - https://www.tpilet.ee/en

Line Tallin - Tartu is really frequented one so you can snatch good deals if you buy in advance.